# How to reference instance of factory created class in Typescript? Cannot find name error

Tags: typescript

Typescript is failing to reference factory created class.
Here's an example code:

```
// factory.ts
export const createClass = () =>
  class Model {
    // ...
  }

// ModelA.ts
import {createClass} from './factory';

export const ModelA = createClass();

let a: ModelA; // Cannot find name 'ModelA';

// other.ts
import {ModelA} from './ModelA';
new ModelA() // Cannot find name 'ModelA';
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try `let a: typeof ModelA`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get the insurance type for the class generated by the function then you can use the `InstanceType` conditional type.

```
export const createClass = () =>
class Model {
    // ...
}


export const ModelA = createClass();
type ModelA = InstanceType<typeof ModelA>
let a: ModelA = new ModelA(); // ok
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this in `ModelA.ts`

```
export const ModelA = createClass();
export type ModelA = typeof ModelA;
```

Edit (credits for Joon), for future readers

The solution above apparently doesn't work as you're unable to

```
const foo: ModelA = new ModelA()
  //Type 'Model' is not assignable to type 'typeof Model'. Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'Model'.
```

One proposed in comment works

```
export type ModelA = typeof ModelA['prototype'];
```

(not sure why though).

Comment: Actually, this does not work because typeof ModelA references type of class itself. I think it should be `typeof ModelA['prototype']`

Comment: Strange, it works for me on typescript 2.9.2. What version do you use ? I see that there is kind-a self-reference but it can easily solved with naming. The overall solution of exporting both type and var(modulo naming) is even recommended here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10058#issuecomment-236458961

Comment: I see that now, ts-node accepts that code, but VS Code shows errors. Strange.