# Type reference to constructor of a class in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to reference the type of a class constructor itself, not its instance.

```
class A {
  static a = 1;
  b = 2;
}

let a: A; // a is an instance of A
a.b === 2 // this works as expected

let aClass: A['constructor'];
aClass.a // not found in Typescript
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `typeof A` to reference the class itself and not an instance of the class, and the class is represented by the constructor

```
let aClass: typeof A =A
aClass.a //ok
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51454166/how-to-reference-instance-of-factory-created-class-in-typescript-cannot-find-na .The correct answer should be `export type ModelA = typeof ModelA['prototype'];`

Comment: @Joon actually I think you are looking for the instance type there, added my own answer